How do i filter a dataframe to get a specific letter at a specific place
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("skribble\Skribbl-words.csv")) 
keyword_len = int(input('Number of total letters of the keyword: '))
hint1 = input('type hint no. 1 :')
hint1_pos = input('position of hint 1 in keyword :')
hint2 = input('type hint no. 2 :')
hint2_pos = input('position of hint 2 in keyword :')
plausiblewords = d1.loc[d1['count'] == keyword_len]
print(plausiblewords)


this is the code i wrote just for some fun while playing skribble.io online with friends and got curious if i could narrow down the words of the plausible keyword the current word allows me to a dataframe of keywords with a specific no. of letters but i need help to further filter it down by the hints we get in a usual game which is 2 most of the time, i need to filter the dataframe so that i get all the keywords that have that specific letter at that specific place. I don't want it to be a dataframe in specific list works too.
i have tried further using loc but i can't get around doing it and i am a beginner so i don't know what to do, if someone could tell me what to do with a brief explanation it would help a lot.

What I would do is throw out pandas and do this in straight Python.  It's easy there -- just a couple of functions to filter the list down.  You're fighting the tool.

i agree with @Tim Roberts ,  unless you have a large list the the benefits of pandas vectorisation are negated by the code complexity...  just filter the list.  The only benefit of pandas here is a convenient way or reading a csv file :)

mask = (df['column_name'].str[hint1_pos] == hint1), filtered_df = df[mask]

for two chars it may need & like mask = (df['column_name'].str[hint1_pos] == hint1) & (df['column_name'].str[hint2_pos] == hint2)

Aside: pd.read_csv() returns a dataframe, there's no need to wrap pd.DataFrame() around it.

If you have strings in column (ie. word) then you can use .str to make some operation on strings
mask = (df['word'].str[hint1_pos] == hint1)

filtered_df = df[mask]

For more chars you can use & (for AND) | (for OR)
mask = (df['word'].str[hint1_pos] == hint1) & (df['word'].str[hint2_pos] == hint2)

filtered_df = df[mask]

It can be important to use brackets (...) & (...) and (...) | (...).
You can also use brackets to create more complex masks.

With more rules you can write it also more readable
mask0 = (df['count'] == keyword_len)
#mask0 = (df['word'].str.len() == keyword_len)
mask1 = (df['word'].str[hint1_pos] == hint1)
mask2 = (df['word'].str[hint2_pos] == hint2)

mask = mask0 & mask1 & mask2

filtered_df = df[mask]


if you have even more chars then you could keep them on list and use for-loop
mask = (df['count'] == keyword_len)

for pos, hint in [(hint1_pos, hint1), (hint2_pos, hint2)]:
    temp_mask = (df['word'].str[pos] == hint)
    mask &= temp_mask

filtered_df = df[mask]


You may also use .apply(function) on column word to generate mask
It needs function which returns True or False
def filter_word(word):
    return len(word) == keyword_len and word[hint1_pos] == hint1 and word[hint2_pos] == hint2
    
mask = df['word'].apply(filter_word)

filtered_df = df[mask]

You may also use .apply(function) on full rows
def filter_word(row):
    return row['count'] == keyword_len and row['word'][hint1_pos] == hint1 and row['word'][hint2_pos] == hint2
    
mask = df.apply(filter_word, axis=1)

filtered_df = df[mask]


Minimal working code with example data
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'word': ['hello', 'halo', 'hell', 'hold', 'hellada']})
df['count'] = df['word'].str.len()
print(df)

print('--- count ---')

mask = (df['count'] == 4)
print(df[mask])

print('--- (...) & (...) & (...) ---')

mask0 = (df['count'] == 4)
#mask0 = (df['word'].str.len() == 4)
mask1 = (df['word'].str[2] == 'l')
mask2 = (df['word'].str[3] == 'l')
mask = mask0 & mask1 & mask2
print(df[mask])

print('--- loop ---')

mask = (df['count'] == 4)
for pos, hint in [(2, 'l'), (3, 'l')]:
    temp_mask = (df['word'].str[pos] == hint)
    mask &= temp_mask

#print(mask)
print(df[mask])

print('--- apply word ---')

def filter_word(word):
    return len(word) == 4 and word[2] == 'l' and word[3] == 'l'
    
mask = df['word'].apply(filter_word)
#print(mask)
print(df[mask])

print('--- apply row ---')

def filter_row(row):
    return row['count'] == 4 and row['word'][2] == 'l' and row['word'][3] == 'l'

mask = df.apply(filter_row, axis=1)
#print(mask)
print(df[mask])

